# How to set session oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

SUPPOSE If i run any form in apex and then I will update any record then they get capture "APEX_PUBLIC_USER".
I want to capture my login user id by default using login URL

how to solve this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice in APEX to capture the audit fields (created_by, created, updated_by, update) is to use a trigger on the table. That way no coding is needed in apex itself.

Suppose you have a table rahul with a column "name" that you want to add records to via apex. Then you'd just create a form with the page item `P1_NAME` and let the database handle the other columns for you with the trigger.

```
create table rahul (
    id                             number generated by default on null as identity 
                                   constraint koen_id_pk primary key,
    name                           varchar2(255 char),
    created                        date not null,
    created_by                     varchar2(255 char) not null,
    updated                        date not null,
    updated_by                     varchar2(255 char) not null
)
;


-- triggers
create or replace trigger rahul_biu
    before insert or update 
    on rahul
    for each row
begin
    if inserting then
        :new.created := sysdate;
        :new.created_by := coalesce(sys_context('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER'),user);
    end if;
    :new.updated := sysdate;
    :new.updated_by := coalesce(sys_context('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER'),user);
end rahul_biu;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand what

> I want to capture my login user id by default using login URL

means, but - user who is currently logged in is contained in `:APP_USER` so I suggest you use it.